# Why aren't .html files allowed as resumes on careers.stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, jobs

I recently went to apply to a job by the title of "web developer" on Careers.Stackoverflow.com and when I went to upload my HTML resume, I got an error that it's not allowed.

I really try to prove that I know HTML and CSS with my HTML resume. It covers edge cases such as printing the exact same way as it looks on the screen and such.

I think that converting my HTML resume to a PDF would actually hurt my chances of getting the job because they can't immediately know I know HTML and CSS well and can do web design.

I really do not understand the reasoning behind not allowing HTML resumes though.

Is there someone who can explain why they don't allow them, or if there is some technical limitation to them or what?

Comment: Just a hunch: if I would name it "See what the community thinks of this user" and then make the content look like an official Careers page? (Still then, I can see why it might be useful.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're requesting a security vunerablity

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Well, right now what I usually end up doing is finding the job posting on stackoverflow and then looking on the companies website for an email address. I'm sure this isn't their intended flow, and I'm pretty sure that there have been more doc, docx, and pdf vulnerabilities than html vulnerabilities.

Comment: I assume @SomeHelpfulCommenter is referring to including JavaScript in your HTML, and then have that loaded from the same Careers domain, which might allow for accessing other Careers pages as if you were the other user. (It wouldn't be too nice if your JavaScript could reveal which employer is peeking into your profile. Worse if it would fool the other user into doing some actions.)

Comment: @Arjan Easily defeated. Just have resumes loaded from an alternate domain and/or have the mime-type set though that any sane browser will "download" the resume rather than view it

Comment: Sure, Earl, I think you're right.

Answer (score 4):

The number of people who actually apply to jobs by sending an html file through email is very low.  In the case that people do want to show their html and css chops, they typically create a profile for themselves somewhere on a webpage and link that web page directly from the cover letter.

Comment: Also, your resume is not your portfolio.

Comment: @Wooble of course it's not. But I thought it was quite common for anyone applying for a job like `web developer` to have an HTML resume. I guess I overestimated how many people use HTML for resumes

Comment: Also though. I don't understand why you would disallow HTML resumes. It's obviously a heard of format and such, and there isn't really any drawbacks to allowing them

Comment: @Earlz The drawback to every feature you ever implement is called maintenance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!